# legitimate software source, or malware?

Tags: ms-office, malware

Needing to upgrade to a 64-bit version of Microsoft Office (in order to upgrade to Mac OS Catalina or Big Sur), I sought out a deal on Office 2019.

After paying, I received an email with the installation instructions.   I was expecting to receive a "key" which I could then use to download from Microsoft's website.  Instead, I received two links to "download and install".   The first appeared to be from go.microsoft.com, but when I typed it in (instead of clicking on the link in the email) I got "the page requested could not be found".  When I simply clicked on the link, it downloaded what appeared to be a Microsoft Office Installer dot-pkg file; needless to say, I have not opened that file.   The second was a tinyurl link, which went to a domain called ln2.sync.com, where I was asked to download a file called "Microsoft_Office_2019_VL_Serializer.pkg" (which I did not do).

Does this all seem legit, or an attempt to installed Malware on my computer ?   If the latter, is there any recourse, or should I just suck up the $50, be glad I caught it in time, and resolve not to be such a cheapskate in the future ?

Comment: A "serializer" is often a program designed to make pirated software work without a serial number (hence the name). I would bet that you downloaded (at the least) a pirated copy of MS Office.

Comment: & "VL" would be the Volume Licensing edition. I'd be looking into who you bought it from & how to get your money back.

Comment: So probably not malware, but probably not legit either ?

Comment: Hmm, well I confronted them and they claim they are an authorized re-seller and it is not pirated.   I said I would contact Microsoft to verify this.   I asked if they would simply give me a refund, and they immediately did so - at least Paypal says there is one in progress.    So maybe they are legit.   Or maybe I scared them.

Comment: Got what appears a fully legit copy for $80 from another source.

Comment: You probably just scared them… a bit. They still have another thousand licences they can sell to other people… until the VL license 'block' runs out, then they'll just buy [or hack] another to sell off in bits. It's against MS EULA, VL licences *should* all be within one organisation. It's 'legal' if they bought the Volume License… but not moral. That entire VL license block may at some future point be rescinded by MS, if they spot it.

Comment: Should I name the outfit ?

Comment: Not really much point - they'll just move on… new name, do it over...